# how can i set "size" for the tag select using typescript and react,

Tags: reactjs, typescript, size

```
export default function StatesSelect(){
  return(
    <StatesSelectStyled>
    <label htmlFor="">Primeiro gostaríamos de saber em qual estado você trabalha</label>
    <select name="estados" size="2">
      <option value="default"></option>
```

I get an error trying to use **size** there, error:

```
(property) React.SelectHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>.size?: number | undefined
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(2406, 9): The expected type comes from property 'size' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<SelectHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>, HTMLSelectElement>'
```

How can I fix this? I need to use `size` there.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this code is written within a `.tsx` or `.jsx` file, so you could do the following:

```html
<select name="estados" size={2}>
```